# salesforce SOAP sobject to xml code C#

Tags: c#, soap, type-conversion, salesforce, integration

Hi I'm developing a WPF application by using salesforce partner WSDL as web reference nothing but as soap reference. I'm getting records and i'm doing all **operations** like query,queryMore,search,create,update etc. I know the record are in the format of sObject and this sObject having xml record which are nothing but xml element.
But what i need here I want that total records which are getting from above operations as a xml file.

My sample code is here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using TestForPartnerWSDL.sforce;
namespace TestForPartnerWSDL
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SforceService partnerConnection= null;
        LoginResult loginResult = null;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Login())
            {
                #region Select Query   
                // SOQL query to use 
        String soqlQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact limit 100";
               // Make the query call and get the query results
        QueryResult qr = partnerConnection.query(soqlQuery);
            SObject[] records = qr.getRecords();      

            }

        }

        private bool Login()
        {
            string userName = "MYorgUSERNAME";
            string password = "password";
            service = new SforceService();
            loginResult = new LoginResult();

            try
            {
                loginResult = service.login(userName, password);
            }            

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }           

            //Change the binding to the new endpoint
            service.Url = loginResult.serverUrl; // Set the returned service endpoint URL

            //Create a new session header object and set the session id to that returned by the login
            service.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
            service.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = loginResult.sessionId; // Set the SOAP header with the session ID returned by the login result. This will be included in all API calls.
            // Return true to indicate that we are logged in, pointed at the right URL and have our security token in place.  
            return true;
        }

    public sealed class temperaryclass
    {
        //i used this temporary class for getting records using custom constrecter.
    }    
}
```

Here i need to xml code from **records** object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is somewhat difficult to understand with how your question is worded... I think what you're asking is, "How can I get all of the contacts in the `records` object to output as an XML file?" Is that correct?

Comment: Because you are using the Salesforce SDK, you have an actual model and not just XML. You normally shouldn't need to worry about the XML, just use the model's provided methods and fields. If you really want the XML, you can either serialize the object to XML with something like `XmlSerializer` or you can pull the data from SF using basic HTTP requests rather than the web service reference. If you make a standard HTTP call against their SOAP endpoint, the returned payload will be XML.